# Is there a way to make Public Composer Instances to Private Without Recreating Environments in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer, orchestration, google-cloud-networking

I am currently facing a challenge with our public Composer instances on Google Cloud Platform. We want to make these instances private and restrict public IPs without going through the process of recreating the Composer environment. I am aware that one option is to migrate to new environments using snapshots, but this might result in history loss / require redeploying / duplicate DAG runs due to catchup.

I am reaching out to see if there is an alternative solution, even if it involves manual steps, that would allow us to achieve our goal of making the instances private without without recreating the composer environmentS.

Any suggestions, tips, or guidance would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

Checked the google cloud documentation , but couldn't find any solutions/workarounds.